# Sequence Diagram from Class Diagram

Tags: uml, class-diagram, sequence-diagram, staruml

I'm doing a little UML project where an User has to buy a ticket through the use of a credit card (that he/she owns).
There are 3 types of ticket: single use ticket, half day ticket and full day ticket, all of which are subclass of the abstract Ticket class.

The sequence diagram must represent the action of buying one of these kind of ticket, however I'm struggling to implement it (I'm using STARUML for this project).

[image]

This is how I would had it implemented
[image]

Comment: Well, it could be anything. Who will know how it should work without a spec? Please be specific where you struggle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using the correct element for this: A *combined fragment with alt-operator*.

However, some things are unclear: In your operands you have a text (e.g."Single Use"). I wonder what this is. If it is a guard, then it needs to be in square brackets. Typically the guard will use some attribute of the type represented by the lifeline with the first message in the operand, `Ticket` in this case. It doesn't have such an attribute, but we could interpret this as the result of some `TypeOf()`-function.

The next thing is, that a `Ticket` generalizes `Single Use Ticket`, so each object of type `Single Use Ticket` is also a `Ticket`. Then, why is a `Ticket` object communicating with a `Single Use Ticket` object? That would only make sense, if `Ticket` had an association to `Single Use Ticket`, which it hasn't. Therefore, the four `Ticket` lifelines should be only one and all the `getCost`-messages would be directed to the same lifeline that sends them.

I understand, that you want to express, that the implementation of `getCost` depends on the type of ticket. However, this would only be visible in a sequence diagram, when the implementation leads to different messages being sent. This is not the case here.

It is also strange, that `Ticket.buy` expects a parameter of type `Ticket`. When you send a `buy`-message to a `Ticket` object, what is it supposed to do with another `Ticket` object?

One mistake in the diagram is, that your reply messages are not consistent with the synchroneous messages. Reply messages must return to the lifeline, that sent the synchroneous message, because "synchroneous" means that the sender is waiting for the reply.

You are using found messages for the messages coming from the user. I would rather use messages from the frame of the diagram, because in principle you know, where they come from, you just choose not to model it.

One final recommendation: Lifelines can represent attributes or parameters. Therefore, you should show the name of the parameter or attribute in the head of the lifeline, e.g. `cc:Credit card`. If you are omitting the name, the colon in front of the type remains.